# Apply for UK tourist visa for 6 days

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

I want to apply for a UK tourist visa for my family and me. We have travelled before to Austria, the US, and Italy. My brother lives in the UK, he has a work visa which will expire next August and they will renew it after, we were thinking to visit a city near his so that we can meet during our visit. We will reserve a hotel for us and for him also at that city during our stay.
Is it wise to apply now when his visa is about to expire? I am hesitant about that.

Also there was an amount of money that was deposited to my bank account as a refund from a credit card, and the bank does not want to give a paper justifying the refund, it is written in the bank statement as “refund and card number” (with some stars in the middle).
Would that affect my application?